# get complex collection Using "with" method for deeper relationship models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following models

- Order (id,number)
- Detail (id,item_id,count,user_id ...etc)
- Item (id,name)
- Cat (id,name)
- User (id,name) which is not important in my case

Each order has Many details

Each detail belong to item

Each item belong to category

Each detail belong to user

I wrote this line of code

```
 public function show(Order $order)
{
    //

    $orders= $order->details()->with(['item','user'])->get();
    return response()->json(['details'=>$orders],200);
}
```

to obtains a response like this :

```
"details": [
        {
            "id": 3089,
            "count": 3,
            "item_id": 102,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 10,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:23",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:23",
            "user": {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Ms. Eda Stoltenberg DVM",
                "username": "Brandy Murazik",
                "verified": "1",
                "verification_token": null,
                "status": "1",
                "dept_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 102,
                "code": "Lamar Hansen",
                "cat_id": 91,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:54",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:54"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3428,
            "count": 1,
            "item_id": 15,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 10,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:41",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:41",
            "user": {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Ms. Eda Stoltenberg DVM",
                "username": "Brandy Murazik",
                "verified": "1",
                "verification_token": null,
                "status": "1",
                "dept_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 15,
                "code": "Hilario Dicki",
                "cat_id": 20,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:51",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:51"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3493,
            "count": 1,
            "item_id": 129,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 6,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:45",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:19:45",
            "user": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Prof. Marina Kiehn",
                "username": "Nickolas Hessel",
                "verified": "0",
                "verification_token": "mwWkL95jjyi5di9PSH3T3LXXZEE1W2DmegTxAOtN",
                "status": "1",
                "dept_id": 3,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 129,
                "code": "Dr. Donnell Harber",
                "cat_id": 54,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:55",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:55"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4032,
            "count": 1,
            "item_id": 221,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 8,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:10",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:10",
            "user": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Prof. Thaddeus Boehm",
                "username": "Frederick Kshlerin",
                "verified": "1",
                "verification_token": null,
                "status": "1",
                "dept_id": 3,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:47"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 221,
                "code": "Maia Hettinger V",
                "cat_id": 57,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:58",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:58"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4311,
            "count": 1,
            "item_id": 139,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 3,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:21",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:21",
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Cletus Walter I",
                "username": "Johan Kemmer",
                "verified": "0",
                "verification_token": "M6MWe7mOmzcyM0rrlbMwVCX7q2vyULFKwSAJmQwl",
                "status": "0",
                "dept_id": 5,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:46",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:46"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 139,
                "code": "Tanner Schimmel",
                "cat_id": 80,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:55",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:55"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4821,
            "count": 2,
            "item_id": 243,
            "order_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:41",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:20:41",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mrs. Fay Cassin",
                "username": "Ryley Bode",
                "verified": "0",
                "verification_token": "E93hzJbIp2eCxbBGgtcsYDckRreASTPL6ZEAyyKP",
                "status": "1",
                "dept_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:46",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:46"
            },
            "item": {
                "id": 243,
                "code": "Miss Jaida Simonis DVM",
                "cat_id": 53,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:59",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 22:15:59"
            }
        }
    ]
```

But i also need to get category object inside item object, which is already relationship  is Item belong to Category
I know that i can make a join query but i prefer to find a best solution with relation based between models

So how can i do that if it is possible?

thanks

Comment: `$orders= $order->details()->with(['item.category','user'])->get();`

Comment: Yesssssss,
Worked like a charmmm
I swear that i have tried this but i don't know why it was not working hahaha
You saved me

Comment: Thanks my friend

Answer (score 2):

You may try this (Since item belongs to category):

```
$orders = $order->details()->with(['item.category', 'user'])->get();
```

Comment: its nice seeing you around again